# opencvjs - convert python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I am trying to convert the following `python` code using `opencv` for image processing into `javascript` using `opencvjs`, but seem to be missing something as the output is not quite the same.

Would be great if someone could help me out here as the docs for `opencvjs` are few and far between.

`python` code:

```
img = cv.imread(inPath)
frame_HSV = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
frame_mask = cv.inRange(frame_HSV, (30, 50, 0), (80, 255, 255))

frame_mask = cv.bitwise_not(frame_mask)
frame_result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = frame_mask)
cv.imwrite(outPath, frame_result)
```

My `javascript` code:

```
const src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
const dst = new cv.Mat();
const hsv = new cv.Mat();
const hsvMask = new cv.Mat();
const hsvMaskInv = new cv.Mat();

cv.cvtColor(src, hsv, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 0);


const low = new cv.Mat(hsv.rows, hsv.cols, hsv.type(), [30, 50, 0, 0]);
const high = new cv.Mat(hsv.rows, hsv.cols, hsv.type(), [80, 255, 255, 255]);

cv.inRange(hsv, low, high, hsvMask);

cv.bitwise_not(hsvMask, hsvMaskInv);
cv.bitwise_and(src, src, dst, hsvMaskInv);

cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
src.delete();
dst.delete();
low.delete();
high.delete();
hsv.delete();
hsvMask.delete();
hsvMaskInv.delete();
```

The original image:

[image]

What python outputs:

[image]

What my javascript outputs:

[image]

Comment: you could use the same names for variables to better recognize if you run the same code in both languages. And you could display results after every modification to see if you get the same results in both versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **TL;DR**

Try replacing `COLOR_BGR2HSV` with `cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV`.

### **Implementation**

Comparing `opencv-python 4.5.3.56` with `opencv.js 3.4.0`, the image being read had the green and red channels swapped.

A direct translation of your python code would look like this:

```
// img = cv.imread(inPath)
let img = cv.imread(imgElement);

// frame_HSV = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
let frameHSV = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(img, frameHSV, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 0);

// frame_mask = cv.inRange(frame_HSV, (30, 50, 0), (80, 255, 255))
let frameMask = new cv.Mat();
let low = new cv.Mat(frameHSV.rows, frameHSV.cols, frameHSV.type(), [30, 50, 0, 0]);
let high = new cv.Mat(frameHSV.rows, frameHSV.cols, frameHSV.type(), [80, 255, 255, 255]);
cv.inRange(frameHSV, low, high, frameMask);

// frame_mask = cv.bitwise_not(frame_mask)
cv.bitwise_not(frameMask, frameMask);

// frame_result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = frame_mask)
let frameResult = new cv.Mat();
cv.bitwise_and(img, img, frameResult, frameMask);

// cv.imwrite(outPath, frame_result)
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', frameResult);

img.delete(); frameHSV.delete(); frameMask.delete();
low.delete(); high.delete(); frameResult.delete();
```

### **Debug Method**

You could try logging the images as matrices, so the swapped channels would be easily spotted, but I resorted to furas' suggestion above: display the results after every modification. Here are the results of your Python code and your JavaScript code, respectively:

[image: comparison]